# What makes complex numbers so dominant among two-dimensional scalar fields?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, scalar-fields

Complex numbers are a two-dimensional field. But other 2d fields can be defined. **Edit:** That is incorrect, no other 2d scalar field can be defined.

For example, the standard vector addition and the following multiplication would also obey the field definition.
$$ \begin{pmatrix}a\\b \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}c\\d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}ac\\bd \end{pmatrix}$$

What then makes the complex number multiplication so universally useful? Why are other 2d fields so rarely used and discussed?

Comment: The entry-wise product **does not** satisfy field definition, since $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ is a zero divisor. In fact the complex number is the only dimension-$2$ algebra over $\Bbb{R}$ that is a field.

Comment: @Zerox Do you have a link to the proof? Perhaps you could post that as the answer to the question, so that I can mark it as correct.

Comment: You can have a look at [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)).

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/829560/86421) answer has a sketch of the reasoning for the uniqueness of $\mathbb{C}$.